# How to COUNTIF "=#N/A" from a pivot table on another sheet?

Tags: excel, count, pivot, formula

I've been struggling with this for hours now.
I have a pivot table that reads off of a data sheet which is ran by someone else who uses Vlookups. That's set in stone -_-
So some of the results come back "#N/A" along with a bunch of other results.

I have a 3rd sheet that reads off the pivot table with a bunch of countifs, sums, etc. I'm trying to add a formula to that 3rd sheet that says something like "=COUNTIFS(PivotSheet!A:A, "=#N/A")"

However, everytime it counts it as 0. If I do a generic CountIF not blank, it will find every used cell. So its like it knows those cells have #N/A in them, but doesn't know that it is "#N/A".

I cannot get the formula to read it. I've also tried NA() and some other suggestions from other questions, but none seem to relate to this. Please help!
Here's an attachment to help show my issue:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `=COUNTIFS(PivotSheet!A:A, NA())` (without quotes)?

Comment: Alternatively, you can encompass your formulas with `IFERROR()` and have it return something a little more quantifiable.

Comment: I have tried NA() with and without quotes.

They will/can not add "IfError()" to their vlookup formulas so I am stuck with #N/A results.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to count the instances of the *error* `#N/A`, then do this:

```
= COUNTIF(D3:D6,NA())
```

If you are trying to count the instances of the *text* `#N/A`, then do this:

```
= COUNTIF(D3:D6,"#N/A")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, As I mentioned in the original post, the CountIf(s) doesn't work with trying to count #N/A off of a pivot table result. 
I ended up just having to work around the solution by telling my sheet to look for each of the other possible results other than the #N/As and then subtract that from the total number of cells and that is the count of #N/As in the column pivot. I think this just might be a rare oversight/limitation of excel pivots and formulas. Thank you for the post!

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNT, IF and ISERROR

E.g. if your table range is A1:C3

=COUNT(IF(ISERROR(A1:C3),1,""))

What ISERROR does is treat errors as 1

Comment: Just tried it; that doesn't work either. The result is already #N/A when I get the data. So there are no "errors". Also, it still ignores the #N/A anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that to work on a pivot table you can't simply write `"#N/A"` because pivot tables aren't treating that as an error, you have to do the following to get a work around:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D6,"*N/A")
```

The "*" wildcard breaks it from treating it as an error and will count what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your pivot table only has Row Labels and doesn't appear to do anything with them.  If you drag the same field "Returned Results" to the Values area of the Pivot Table, it should default to "Count of Returned Results".  (Your formula appears to be counting just those four Row Labels, which are of course text format.)

If somehow that isn't your situation and you need a formula that will count these right in a different kind of situation, the following array formula will work.  (To enter an array formula, type the formula and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter.  The cell contents will then appear surrounded by curly braces.)  The formula (for whatever range A:A):

=SUM(IF(ISERROR(A:A),1))-SUM(IF(ISERR(A:A),1))

Like the above suggestions, however, this will also count cells that just contain the typed text "#N/A".